# I want to get a float return with two decimal places when input int like 5 or string like '5' in PHP

Tags: php

How to get **float** return like this:

```
INPUT : int(5) or '5'
RETURN : float(5.00)
```

number_format or sprintf will return **string**

Comment: number_format('500',2)

Comment: For further detail please review this http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid - You should add that as an actual answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @Difster It doesn't, strictly speaking, answer the question. `number_format` returns a string, which the OP said they didn't want.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid Thanks. But that return string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

A `float` is just a number. It doesn't have a number of decimal places -- `5.0` and `5.00` and `5.00000` are all the same value.

Comment: That's actually not true, see https://3v4l.org/d0PRi.

Comment: Thanks. But why can not be  displayed with different form?

Comment: It can be displayed with different form, using it's string representation with number_format function. Float is just a number with floating point, no more, no less. There is no need for formatting in calculations, and for representation string form is used.